# Strange padding around reputation on Meta profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, per-site-meta

The way reputation is displayed on a user's profile page on meta sites is a bit off. There's gray padding around it:

[image]

which is not visible on the main site:

[image]

The 'top x%' label being so close to it makes it even worse.

This affects both [sites with the new design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=topactivity) and [sites without](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11110/glorfindel?tab=topactivity).

Comment: Cross-site post on MSO: [Reputation Card Top % overall label Margin Top missing - Activity Tab, Profile Section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389575/4642212).