# Reputation on Activity tab has an ugly gray background (child metas only)

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, per-site-meta

The reputation on the profile Activity tab (on child meta sites) has a gray square background that also extends all the way to the edge of the next div (text below the reputation).

Using Stack Overflow as an example, compare how it looks on the [main site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) (light theme) vs [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current):

[image: Demo]

The div has a `bg-black-050` class which is responsible for this gray background.

Comment: Duplicate of [Strange padding around reputation on Meta profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316777/strange-padding-around-reputation-on-meta-profile-page), though I couldn’t find it by searching; I had to search through my browser history.

Comment: @user289905 Good find. I did try to look for a dup before posting but couldn't find any. Thank you!